# how to mapped java embbeded object with JSON

Tags: java, json, object

I build an google Calendar API, and i miss understand a point with my json files.

I succeed to create my java object with my json files but here the issue:

i have two classes :

````
public class User {
    private String email;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    Entity entity;
 ``

and my Entity

``  public class Entity {
    private String  name;
    private String entityType;
    private Entity rootEntity;``

here my json file :
for user

``[
  {
    "firstname": "Jean-Marc",
    "lastname": "Chevereau",
    "email": "xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com",
    "entity": {
        "name":"BFA",
        "entityType":"secteur"
    }
  },
    {
    "firstname": "Florent",
    "lastname": "Hamlin",
    "email": "xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com",
     "entity": {
        "name":"IT",
        "entityType":"secteur"
    }
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Benoit",
    "lastname": "Micaud",
    "email": "xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com",
    "entity": {
        "name":"EX",
        "entityType":"offre",
        "rootEntity":{
            "name":"BFA"
          }
        }
      }
    ]``

And a Entity json file

```[ 
   {
    "name": "BFA",
    "entityType": "secteur",
    "rootEntity": "",

  },
  {
   "name": "EX",
    "entityType": "Offre",
    "rootEntity": "BFA",
    }
  }
]
````

But here the trouble. if in my User.json  i write theEntity Name, i dont want to write entitytype and rootEntity, because if i write Entity Name is BFA, it will always be the same entitType and the rootEntity.
In others words, my json Entity will be always the same,and if i just put the name we know that refers to an entity object.

For instance, in this user.json file,  I will just need to put

```
[
  {
    "firstname": "Jean-Marc",
    "lastname": "Chevereau",
    "email": "xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com",
    "entity": {
        "name":"BFA",

    }
  },
    {
    "firstname": "Florent",
    "lastname": "Hamlin",
    "email": "xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com",
     "entity": {
        "name":"IT",

    }
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Benoit",
    "lastname": "Micaud",
    "email": "xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com",
    "entity": {
        "name":"EX",
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose com.fasterxml.jackson's @JsonIgnore annotation should help.

```
public class Entity {
    private String  name;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String entityType;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Entity rootEntity;
}
```

Comment: I dont put de data in DB tho, my goal is to build object of list User and use it with for the api

Comment: That's part of the [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library.

Answer (score 0):

In [Json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) you have a `JsonConfig` to specify the allowed fields:

```java
JsonConfig jsonConfig=new JsonConfig();
jsonConfig.registerPropertyExclusion(Entity.class,"rootEntity");
jsonConfig.registerPropertyExclusion(Entity.class,"entityType");

JSON json = JSONSerializer.toJSON(objectToWrite,jsonConfig);
```

Comment: i am Using jackson lib, but where i dont understand, is why Exlude attribut?  in that case i just dont write it on the json file and it work as well. My wish is to map entity name in user.file object to an entity object with his attribut already set

Comment: @RaphaelObadia You did not write that your problem is to deserialize the JSON to Java. From "``i dont want to write entitytype and rootEntity``" we assumed you wanted to exclude some parts while serializing. In Jackson you can define and register your own [Deserializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) for the Entity class.

Comment: nice, i just didnt know that Deserialize was my issue here :D. now i know where to looking for.